Generate access token for Listing the users of the group using graph Explorer or Postman
I am just trying to explore Azure and Graph explorer, Want to post the web application and group with users using   to read the users of group. I tried but getting an error of Insufficient privileges.I am ok with both Graph Explorer or Postman use any of this
I tried but I am getting the error of insufficient privileges.

Could you include more details on what exactly you want here by including code you tried and errors if any?

I am getting error mssge of insufficient privileges and I want to list the group with members which I created, Thankyou.

Are you getting error in Graph Explorer or Postman? What API permissions you granted for application?

Please include Portal and error screenshots by editing your question

I granted for Application Type Permission

What permissions you granted?

I granted for Application type permission, Getting error on Postman and granted for Application type permission

Did you grant admin consent to those permissions? Please include Portal snip by editing your question

Got it, I missed to grant admin consent.

Error occurred as you missed granting the admin consent  to the added API permissions.
Using below HTTPS command Created an application:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Display name"
}


Created an application with default setting:

To resolve the error, add  GroupMember.Read.All  permission of  Application  type and make sure to grant admin consent.
Granted API Permission **GroupMember.Read.All** with Admin Consent:

Now after creating application, I'll create group with adding members to it. I used below command
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "Group with desmembers",
  "displayName": "Testing55Group",
  "groupTypes": [
  ],
  "mailEnabled": false,
  "mailNickname": "Testing55",
  "securityEnabled": true,

  "members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1-id",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user2-id"
  ]
}
By using above command, we created two members for that group.

Note: Select the Members of the Group by user-id of the User.

Now, Generating Access token using Client Credential Flow with the help of Postman,
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials 
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Access token :

Now, listing the Members of the Group which created with the help of group-id.
Use below command:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group-id/members

References:
Document Related to Group.Member.ReadAll
List Members of Group
